# procedimiento almacenado dentro de una funcion

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Necesito ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado dentro la funcion enviando solamente un ID que es la llave primaria para actualizar un campo de la tabla.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pues no se puede, es así de simple, un límite del motor de base de datos (y hace sentido que no se pueda)

Comment: alguna otra forma, tengo que usar las funciones y procedimientos almacenados

Comment: tendrías que explicar el requerimiento completo, porque difícilmente la solicitud es "tengo que usar una función que ejecute un procedimiento almacenado"

Comment: IV. CONFIGURAR EXAMEN - FUNCIONES
a. Configurar examen tipo falso/verdadero. 
b. Configurar examen tipo selección múltiple 
c. Configurar cantidad de preguntas 
d. Configurar nota del examen 
e. Configurar tiempo de duración del examen.
f. Revisar Examen y generar nota 
g. Registrar plantillas.

Comment: Es la propuesta a.

Comment: para ser honesto….no entiendo lo que se necesita

Comment: la verdad tambien me quede pasmado, tengo que configurar un examen, osea un registro de mi tabla examen, lo que se me vino a la mende fue update, tener creada el registro y luego hacer una actualizacion al Tipo de Examen que son dos False/Verdadero o seleccion multiple

Comment: Así se ejecuta un SP: `EXEC dbo.SP_Examen_Update @idExamen = @IdExamen, @TipoPregunta = 1;` ahora no se cual es el objetivo de hacerlo dentro de una función. El requerimiento lo que esta indicándote son las funciones del sistema, más no que debes hacerlo con funciones de `SQL Server` eso puedes hacerlo tranquilamente con `Procedimientos Almacenados` no te compliques la vida.

Answer (score 1):

Falta un poco de explicar en a pregunta, pero un procedimiento dentro de una funcion no se puede, es una limitante del motor y creo que el fin no es lo que necesitas, sino un cursor, porque quieres modificar por cada id de un select pero así no funciona, sino con un cursor te sera mas fácil actualizar todo.

Funcion del Sql server no es lo mismo que función en un lenguaje de programación, en sql server es limitante y por eso se utilizan procedimientos.

Answer (score 0):

Primero utiliza este comando para activar el xp_cmdshell

/*-- To allow advanced options to be changed.

```
EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO
```

-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.

```
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

-- To enable the feature.

```
EXECUTE sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
GO
```

-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.

```
RECONFIGURE;  
GO*/
```

Luego arias algo como esto

```
CREATE FUNCTION [nombredetufuncion](
@idExamen int,
@var1 (valorquedeseesponer),
@var2 (valorquedeseesponer)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL varchar(4000),@cmd varchar(4000)
    SET @SQL = 'Execute SP_EXAMEN_UPDATE '+@var1+','+@var2
    SELECT @cmd ='sqlcmd -S ' + @@servername + ' -d ' + db_name()+ ' -Q "' + @sql + '"'
    EXEC INSTITUTO..xp_cmdshell @cmd, 'no_output'
    RETURN 1
END
Go
```